# Apt install automatically says "Yes" when trying to install packages

Tags: apt, 17.10

today I ran:

```
sudo apt install unrar
```

and everything was going normal but somehow it skipped the Yes/No stage. Is this normal behaviour after some updates?

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
unrar
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 129 kB of archives.
After this operation, 322 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse amd64 unrar amd64 1:5.5.8-1 [129 kB]
```

As you can see there is no Y/N line in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's normal. You requested installation of a particular package, and no additional packages were needed as dependencies. APT assumed that you really did want to install the package you asked for, and didn't bother to ask you if you were really sure.

If there were additional packages, you would be prompted to confirm that you were OK with installing them, since you hadn't requested them directly.

Comment: You're welcome @KronwarsCZ it took me a while to figure it out!

Comment: Great answer @Zanna!